# Esc fails on vim via ssh through git bash

Tags: ssh, vim, cmd.exe, git-bash

I am a heavy user of vim and, by extension, the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

Today, for the first time, I've noticed that it sometimes sends a literal `[` to the screen instead of changing to command mode as it should. When this occurs, only <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd> works as an <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

This only happens on a remote host I've accessed via SSH through Git Bash, but not on the same host via SSH through cmd.

Here are the versions of my software for reference:

| case | term | ssh |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cmd.exe | cmd (10.0.19041.3636) | OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2 |
| git-bash.exe | git bash (2.38.1.windows.1) | OpenSSH_9.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1q 5 Jul 2022 |

I've noticed when comparing the `env` output in both cases, that the working cmd case shows

```
TERM=xterm-256color
```

whereas the broken case is

```
TERM=xterm
```

Has anyone encountered something similar?

By the way, I'm not sure what other clues might come in handy, so I've pasted the `env` output below:

```bash
SHELL=/bin/bash
CONDA_EXE=/home/user/anaconda3/bin/conda
_CE_M=
LANGUAGE=en_SG:en
EDITOR=/usr/bin/env vim
PWD=/home/user
LOGNAME=user
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
CONDA_PREFIX=/home/user/anaconda3
MOTD_SHOWN=pam
HOME=/home/user
LANG=en_SG.UTF-8
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
SSH_CONNECTION={SRC_IP} {PORT} {DST_IP} 22
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
TERM=xterm-256color
_CE_CONDA=
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
USER=user
CONDA_SHLVL=1
SHLVL=1
XDG_SESSION_ID=5354
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
SSH_CLIENT={SRC_IP} {PORT} 22
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
PATH=/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/anaconda3/bin:/home/user/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/home/user/.local/bin
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/16
_=/usr/bin/env
```